# What is use of campaign tagging to Asset (PDF)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I have tagged campaign and download event to one Asset (PDF) in Sitecore. 
After downloading that PDF file i am able to see download event in xDB, but i am not getting any campaign related information in that record.
Is there any use of tagging campaign to Asset.